# Understanding Recursive Traversal , of and reduce Example

Tags: javascript

I was trying to understand Recursive Transversal.

I stumbled upon this [link](https://javascript.info/recursion) where they wrote something like this for an example

```js
let company = { // the same object, compressed for brevity
  sales: [{name: 'John', salary: 1000}, {name: 'Alice', salary: 600 }],
  development: {
    sites: [{name: 'Peter', salary: 2000}, {name: 'Alex', salary: 1800 }],
    internals: [{name: 'Jack', salary: 1300}]
  }
};

// The function to do the job
function sumSalaries(department) {
  if (Array.isArray(department)) { // case (1)
    return department.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current.salary, 0); // sum the array
  } else { // case (2)
    let sum = 0;
    for (let subdep of Object.values(department)) {
      sum += sumSalaries(subdep); // recursively call for subdepartments, sum the results
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

alert(sumSalaries(company)); // 6700
```

Now, I went and  read about `reduce` and `of` vaguely and I am unable to connect it with this example

Like [as per this article](https://codeburst.io/array-methods-explained-filter-vs-map-vs-reduce-vs-foreach-ea3127c6d319)

> Inside this callback we get two arguments sum & elem. The sum is the
>   last returned value of the reduce function. For example initially the
>   sum value will be 0 then when the callback runs on the first element
>   it will add the elem to the sum and return that value. On second
>   iteration the sum value will be first elem + 0, on third iteration it
>   will be 0 + first elem + second elem.

Now, that example was with array and this is with object but still I am unable to connect *how* can `current.salary`  be equal to the salary?

Then I am literally unable to comprehend this line

```
for (let subdep of Object.values(department)) {
      sum += sumSalaries(subdep); // recursively call for subdepartments, sum the results
    }
```

Like I understand he is calling sumSalaries recursively but.. Still make no sense to me?

Can someone please-please explain this in stretch?

Comment: Perhaps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce is a better resource to learn at least how `reduce` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's step through the code:

#### 1) The function

```
function sumSalaries(department) {
```

`sumSalaries` accepts one argument. Initially this will be an object `company`, but over successive iterations of the object properties this will be either an array or an object.

#### 2) The condition

```
  if (Array.isArray(department)) {
```

We have a condition to be satisfied. If the argument is an array, sum the salary values using `reduce`. Initially the `company` object doesn't meet this condition.

The `sales` array, and both arrays from the `department` object will meet this condition.

#### 3) `reduce`

```
    return department.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current.salary, 0);
```

`reduce` accepts an initial value 0 that will always be the first argument in the callback function *on each iteration*. In this instance it's called `prev`, but could easily be called `acc` for "accumulator", or `sum`, for example. The second argument `current` is the current element in the array.

**Important note**: the elements in these arrays are all **objects**.

So we start with 0 passed in `prev` and the first array object in `current` and we add the value found in that *object's salary property* to zero. This value is passed in as the `prev` argument on the next iteration. We keep adding to this value until there are no more elements to iterate over, and then the result is returned.

#### 4) If the condition isn't met

```
  } else {
    let sum = 0;
```

Both the `company` object, and the `development` object match this condition.

#### 5) The iterative function call

```
    for (let subdep of Object.values(department)) {
      sum += sumSalaries(subdep);
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

On the first iteration we're looping over `company`. Its values are one array (`sales`) and another object (`development`). The array and object get fed back into the function. The array gets reduced and the value added to `sum`, and the object hits satisfies this condition again and each array (`sites`, `internals`) is fed back into the function again and *their* results are reduced and added to the sum.

And that's it! Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please try to answer this question as well? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805979/javascript-why-am-i-not-getting-name-already-exist-error

Answer (score 1):

```
let subdep of Object.values(department)
```

This iterates over the values when `department` is not an array. When sumSalaries 
is first called with `company`, we hit this line of code because `company` is not an array. The values of `company` are the `sales` array and the `development` object - these values are both passed into `sumSalaries`.

Let's look at a simplified example of how the logic would work with pure number values:

```
const test = {
  sites: 3800,
  internals: 1300
}

let sum = 0;
for (let aggSalaries of Object.values(test)) {
  sum += aggSalaries;
}
console.log(sum)
```

> 5100

I would suggest the code can be simplified to:

```js
const company = {
  sales: [{name: 'John', salary: 1000}, {name: 'Alice', salary: 600 }],
  development: {
    sites: [{name: 'Peter', salary: 2000}, {name: 'Alex', salary: 1800 }],
    internals: [{name: 'Jack', salary: 1300}]
  }
};

function sumSalaries(department) {
  return Array.isArray(department)
    ? department.reduce((prev, {salary}) => prev + salary, 0)
    : Object.values(department).reduce((memo, value) => memo + sumSalaries(value), 0);
}

console.log(sumSalaries(company));
```

Comment: Can you please try to answer this question as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805979/javascript-why-am-i-not-getting-name-already-exist-error